# Eagle part for "MiniLED" SMT LED

Tags: led, pcb-design, eaglecad

I'd like to use this LED, but its package is just listed as 'MiniLED' in the datasheet.  Is that a standard package, or just a Vishay term?

Is there an equivalent part already in Eagle 6?  If not, I don't quite understand the  dimensions in the datasheet well enough to create the part myself.

http://www.vishay.com/docs/81233/vlmosy21.pdf

Answer (score 2):

"MiniLED" is not a standard package designator.  There is a mechanical drawing in the datasheet, which shows that the part is 2.2mm long and 1.4mm wide.  This is slightly bigger than the standard 0805 and smaller than the standard 1206.

You probably need to make a custom footprint.  Perhaps, you could modify an existing  1206 footprint.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proposed pad layout on page 7.  The hashed area is copper covered with solder resist. It seems the LED needs a minimum area for cooling, so depending on your layout you might change the shape, maybe increase the area for better cooling (hence the "proposed").

The dimensions are in mm (stated at the top of the page).